# How did I get 111 npm downloads already?

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-install, npm-publish

So 2 days ago I published my [first npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aviatojs), a simple library to trim and join audio files

The weird thing is I already got 111 downloads somehow.
I haven't shared this package with anyone. Neither have I documented anything. The **README** is literally blank.
Could this be a mistake?

Comment: Most likely there are bots out there that download random packages

Comment: It's funny because im reading the question now and your package has 1 download per week :D

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Npm’s download stats are native by design: they are simply a count of the number of HTTP 200 responses we served that were tarball files, i.e. packages. This means the number includes:

- automated build servers
- downloads by mirrors
- robots that download every package for analysis

Full answere there:
https://blog.npmjs.org/post/92574016600/numeric-precision-matters-how-npm-download-counts-work.html.

Comment: i think you meant naive and not native?

Comment: @Zachiah, got a good laugh on the package name.

Answer (score 4):

This is something which occurs pretty often when you upload packages to npm.

One week ago I also pushed a simple project to npm and it got 1.5k downloads in a week.

I do not think this means that 111 people have downloaded your package, but better be safe than sorry.

You should fill up the readme just to be safe.

Comment: “You should fill up the readme just to be safe.” What are the dangers of not doing this?

Comment: @idmean People won't know how to use your library :)

Answer (score 0):

I recently uploaded a package 
[react-native-expo-localstorage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-expo-localstorage) in npm and within 16 hours I got 107 downloads...

But this doesn't mean 107 real people downloaded the package...

`So the count of “downloads” is much larger than the number of people who typed “npm install yourpackage” on any given day.`

[image: 107 downloads within 16 hours]

Comment: @Alvin it does answer, I have included that sentence from npm docs. I said "doesn't mean 107 real people downloaded" and it is assumed that the package may be used by... automated build servers, downloads by mirrors, and robots that download every package for analysis. Sometimes people just don't want details... but just an easy-to-understand answer.

Comment: Fair enough, @anzeqar, but it is necessary to specify it or the answer looks incomplete in the reviewing process

Answer (score 0):

The real reason behind this is npm scanners. npm scanners download your package and if it seems suspicious they report it immediately to npm to remove it.
npm scanners started to show up after the announcement of "dependency confusion" vulnerability.